# Customize Django class base view at global (project wide)

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

I am developer a Django website which will do SSO for most of the web pages, and I was using Class based views extensively, the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) said that we can decorate class based view in this way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've implemented a customized `sso_login_required` decorator, but since most of my pages will do SSO,  I believe doing above for most of my views is **absolutely not the right way**, I was thinking doing that at a global level, I guess I have two options to implement/override the dispatch method above:

1. Create my `BaseView` class which inherits from `django.views.generic.base.View`, and let all my views inherits from this customized BaseView.
2. Override `dispatch` method of `django.views.generic.base.View` at my project level

What is the best practice here according to my requirement (SSO for most pages)? Any recommendation or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, using inheritance seems the way to go, and you can implement your logic as a mixin:

```
from yourproject.decorators import sso_login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class SSOMixin(object):

    @method_decorator(sso_login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SSOMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your other projects views, you can do stuff like:

```
class BaseView(View):
    # your logic here

class ProtectedBaseView(SSOMixin, BaseView)
    # your logic here
```

Using a mixin may be more convenient than putting this logic in your project `BaseView`, especially if you'll have some views that do not require SSO, or if you want to use this logic in views that do not inherit from your `BaseView`.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, that's indeed one feasible way, and I supposed to do so; but eventually I decided to go with marking login_required at urls.py, IMHO that is still better than mixin in this case

Comment: You're right, using decorators in urls is possible too